# Ternary in Laravel Blade to apply row class names

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have this report that Im trying to do, but I want to make the rows alternate colors. this is what I tried, but it does not work. What is the correct way to achieve this?

```
    <div class="row">
    {{$rowOrder = "even"}}
    @foreach($data as $row)
            {{ $rowLine = ($rowOrder = "odd" ? 'even' : 'odd') }}
            <div class="col-sm-4 repColumn {{$rowOrder}}">
                <span>{{$row->adm_referraldate}}</span>
                <span>{{$row->adm_number}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 repColumn {{$rowOrder}}">
                <span>{{$row->dmg_nhsnumber}}</span>
                <span>{{$row->dmg_firstname." ".$row->dmg_surname}}</span>
                <span>{{$row->dmg_dateofbirth." - (".$row->dmg_ageyears.")"}}</span>
                <span>{{$row->dmg_sex}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 repColumn {{$rowOrder}}">
                <span>{{$row->dmg_nhsnumber}}</span>
                <span>{{$row->dmg_firstname." ".$row->dmg_surname}}</span>
                <span>{{$row->dmg_dateofbirth." - (".$row->dmg_ageyears.")"}}</span>
                <span>{{$row->dmg_sex}}</span>
            </div>
    @endforeach
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
{{ $rowLine = ($rowOrder = "odd" ? 'even' : 'odd') }}
```

with

```
<?php $rowOrder = ($rowOrder == "odd") ? 'even' : 'odd'; ?>
```

or if you are using a Laravel 5.2 or up

```
@php($rowOrder = ($rowOrder == "odd") ? 'even' : 'odd')
```

Do the same for the line `{{$rowOrder = "even"}}`

If you used the `{{$rowOrder = "even"}}` it will echo out the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use modulo arithmetic to decide whether and index is odd or even:

$isEven = index % 2

If you combine this with a PHP ternary operator then you'd get this

```
{{ $loop->index % 2 ? 'odd': 'even' }}
```

see

https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators
and
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic

Comment: While this code-only answer may solve the problem at hand, more explanation is necessary to help future users of the site understand how to apply this solution to their situation.

Comment: I was also looking for answer of this problem too, and find this simple answer. after seen this question! and it was answered already. so i putted this short answer for the one he asked this question maybe its useful for him  to reduce his code. that all

Comment: There's nothing wrong in posting such answers. Only thing is, code-only answers get flagged as VLQ and may end up getting deleted. As I said earlier, some explanation may help others understand your solution better (earning you some upvotes) and will also prevent others flagging the answer as VLQ.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very easy solution:

```
    @php $count = 0; @endphp
    @foreach($data as $row)
        <div class="{{ ++$count % 2 ? 'odd': 'even' }}">
            {{ $row->name }}
        </div>
    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

Use variable [$loop documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#the-loop-variable) ( $loop->even laravel 5.8, or ($loop->iteration % 2)laravel< 5.8 )

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    @if ($loop->even)
        This is even.
    @else 

    @endif
@endforeach
```

or

```
@foreach ($listObject as $Object)
                <tr class="{{ ($loop->iteration % 2) ? 'odd' : 'even' }}">
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ $rowLine = ($rowOrder = "odd" ? 'even' : 'odd') }}
```

possibly should be

```
 {{ $rowLine = ($rowOrder == "odd" ? 'even' : 'odd') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example for me: I left the dump output in it so you can see the actual number counting up. Hope it helps anyone who comes across this problem :). EDIT: Don't forget to add colors in your css file for .odd and .even!

```
@if(!empty($names))

{{-- SET VARIABLE + HIDE IT --}}
<div class="hide">{!! $number = 0 !!}</div>

   @foreach($names as $n)

    {{ dump($number) }}

    <div class="{!! $number % 2 == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even'  !!}">

        {{-- UP VARIABLE + HIDE IT --}}
        <div class="hide">{!! $number++ !!}}</div>

        {{-- DISPLAY CONTENT —}}
        {{ $n }}

    </div>

   @endforeach
@endif
```

Answer (score -1):

Try getting the key from the foreach loop and run ($key % 2)
Basically Odd Number mod 2 always have a remainder

```
@foreach ($rows as $key => $row) 
   <div class="@if ($key > 0 && $key % 2) odd @else even @endif">
   </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: why was this voted down? it's the basic concept of 3%2